# Impala/Hive string extract inside square brackets

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I have a string and I need to get the last string inside square brackets using Impala/Hive.

Ex1:

```
String = "rcm_case_items_relation [Alert] Indicator added [Indicator]"
```

The required output should be : Indicator

I tried using regex function something like this but didn't work. Kindly help

```
select regexp_extract("rcm_case_items_relation [Alert] Indicator added [Indicator]",*?([[:[]:]]+).*?',1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex: `(.|\\n)*\\[((.|\\n)*)\\]`

```
select regexp_extract('rcm_case_items_relation [Alert] Indicator added [Indicator]', '(.|\\n)*\\[((.|\\n)*)\\]', 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution was working fine with single line string but not working for multi line string.

Example:

select regexp_extract("FCI SAR Trigger Event Assessment changed from [XXXX123] to [empty]
FCI SAR Other Legal Entity changed from [NO] to [empty]
FCI SAR Other Important Factors changed from [TESTING] to [test case 2 checks]
DISPOSITION_RATIONALE changed from [TEST] to [TEST 2 fixed to check if working]", '.*\\[(.*)\\]', 1); 

The expected output should be: TEST 2 fixed to check if working. Can you please suggest.